# Maven missing from list support frameworks in Intellij

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

Recently after upgrading to Java 8, maven was found missing from the list of support frameworks in Intellij. But maven is configured in the system(used mvn -v).

How can I add back Maven to list of support frameworks